# How to remove empty space in header during loading state in React Navigation?

Tags: javascript, react-native, header, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

`The problem is that when I reload the app, there is a blank space like padding in the navigation header during loading. But when the loading is complete and I enter the homepage, the header returns to normal.
I want the header to return to normal when on the loading page, just like on the homepage.

[image: The header display during loading has a blank or padding-like section.]

[image: Expected header appearance.]

NAVIGATION CODE

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';

import colors from './src/configs/colors';

import Homepage from './src/screens/Homepage';
import Details from './src/components/Details';
import Search from './src/screens/Search';
import Loader from './src/components/loaders/LoaderHome';

export default function App() {
  const Stack = createStackNavigator();

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Movie"
          component={Homepage}
          options={{
            // headerShown: false,
            headerTitle: 'The Movie App',
            headerTitleAlign: 'center',
            headerTintColor: colors.white,
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: colors.black2,
              borderWidth: 2,
              borderColor: '#fff',
              // height: 56,
            },
          }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Details"
          component={Details}
          options={{
            headerTintColor: colors.white,
            headerStyle: {backgroundColor: colors.black2},
          }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Search"
          component={Search}
          options={{
            headerTintColor: colors.white,
            headerStyle: {backgroundColor: colors.black2},
          }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

HOMEPAGE CODE

```
import {
  View,
  Text,
  Image,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ScrollView,
  ActivityIndicator,
} from 'react-native';
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import tmdb from '../apis/tmdb';

import CardPopuler from '../components/cards/CardPopuler';
import CardRecommended from '../components/cards/CardRecommended';
import LoaderHome from '../components/loaders/LoaderHome';

import colors from '../configs/colors';
import category from '../configs/category';

const Homepage = ({navigation}) => {
  const [trendings, setTrendings] = useState([]);
  const [tops, setTops] = useState([]);
  const [active, setActive] = useState(0);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [loader, setLoader] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchTrending = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await tmdb.get('/trending/movie/day');
        setTrendings(response.data.results);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };

    const fetchTop = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await tmdb.get(
          '/movie/top_rated?language=en-US&page=1',
        );
        // setLoader(false);
        setTops(response.data.results);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };

    Promise.all([fetchTrending(), fetchTop()]).then(() => setLoader(false));
  }, []);


  if (loading) {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
          backgroundColor: colors.black,
        }}>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color={colors.white} />
        <Text style={{color: colors.white, fontSize: 16}}>Loading...</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  const submitSearch = async () => {
    setLoading(true);

    const fetchSearch = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await tmdb.get(
          `/search/movie?language=en-US&page=1&query=${search}&include_adult=false`,
        );

        setLoading(false);
        setSearch('');
        navigation.navigate('Search', {
          movies: response.data.results,
          search: search,
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };

    fetchSearch();
  };

  return (
    <ScrollView style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: colors.black}}>
      {loader ? (
        <LoaderHome />
      ) : (
        <View
          style={{
            paddingVertical: 20,
            height: '100%',
          }}>
          <View
            style={{
              flexDirection: 'row',
              justifyContent: 'space-between',
              alignItems: 'center',
              marginHorizontal: 20,
            }}>
            <Text
              style={{
                fontSize: 30,
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                color: colors.white,
              }}>
              Discover
            </Text>
            <Image
              style={{
                height: 50,
                width: 50,
                borderRadius: 50,
              }}
              source={{uri: 'https://reqres.in/img/faces/1-image.jpg'}}
            />
          </View>

          <View
            style={{
              flexDirection: 'row',
              alignItems: 'flex-end',
              justifyContent: 'space-between',
              marginTop: 32,
              marginHorizontal: 20,
            }}>
            <TextInput
              style={{
                color: colors.white,
                borderRadius: 8,
                paddingHorizontal: 20,
                fontSize: 16,
                width: '75%',
                height: 44,
                backgroundColor: colors.black2,
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: colors.white,
              }}
              placeholder="Search"
              placeholderTextColor={colors.white}
              onChangeText={res => setSearch(res)}
            />
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={{
                backgroundColor: colors.yellow,
                padding: 8,
                flex: 1,
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
                marginLeft: 4,
                paddingVertical: 11,
                borderRadius: 8,
              }}
              onPress={async () => await submitSearch()}>
              <Text
                style={{
                  color: colors.black2,
                  fontSize: 16,
                  fontWeight: 'bold',
                }}>
                Submit
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>

          <View
            style={{
              marginTop: 30,
            }}>
            <ScrollView horizontal showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
              {category.map((data, index) => (
                <TouchableOpacity
                  onPress={() => setActive(index)}
                  key={data.id}>
                  <Text
                    style={[
                      {
                        fontSize: 16,
                        color: colors.black2,
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        marginRight: 18,
                        backgroundColor: colors.yellow,
                        paddingVertical: 4,
                        paddingHorizontal: 8,
                        borderRadius: 8,
                      },
                      active === index && {
                        color: colors.yellow,
                        backgroundColor: colors.black2,
                      },
                      index === 0 && {
                        marginHorizontal: 18,
                      },
                    ]}>
                    {data.title}
                  </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              ))}
            </ScrollView>
          </View>

          <View style={{marginTop: 12}}>
            <Text
              style={{
                color: colors.white,
                fontSize: 24,
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                marginBottom: 12,
                marginLeft: 24,
              }}>
              Popular
            </Text>
            <ScrollView horizontal>
              {trendings.map((data, i) => (
                <View key={i} style={i === 0 && {marginLeft: 20}}>
                  <CardPopuler data={data} key={i} />
                </View>
              ))}
            </ScrollView>
          </View>

          <View style={{marginTop: 30}}>
            <Text
              style={{
                color: colors.white,
                fontSize: 24,
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                marginBottom: 12,
                marginLeft: 24,
              }}>
              Recommended
            </Text>
            <ScrollView horizontal>
              {tops.map((data, i) => (
                <View key={i} style={i === 0 && {marginLeft: 20}}>
                  <CardRecommended data={data} key={data.id} />
                </View>
              ))}
            </ScrollView>
          </View>
        </View>
      )}
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

export default Homepage;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Fajar can you share that code within the thread otherwise it's hard to say whats the exact issue.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't see the code in my question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post.
Please do not comment in the answer and take the tour and read How to Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer